# Using a demo slider to figure out how to have the slides flow automatically

Tags: javascript, html, css

```
[slider link][1]
```

Using HTML, CSS, and JS I want to make a slider similar to this demo one however I would like for the slides to flow automatically and pause if moused over.

https://codepen.io/mikun/pen/YWgqEX

Comment: It's very nice, so how can we help?

Comment: Thanks, I would just rather the slides change automatically smililar to this https://codepen.io/IsoLennox/pen/cJfBj and pause on the slide if moused over

Comment: You need to separate the logic outside of the click event binding. That way you can pass the "current" and "next" slide values and change the view accordingly. Then setup a timeout or interval to automatically call the code to change the view. Please attempt this and post your code if you continue to struggle.

Comment: can it be done in pure css or no

Comment: @EmilyMcMullin no you will need to use Javascript/jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of click events just use setInterval(function, 5000); and write the function that switches the slides and the interval will run the function every 5 seconds.

Comment: do you mind giving an example? not asking for you to completely write the function I am just not sure how to start it

Comment: Yeah you get all the slides in an Array [... , ... , ... , ]. then you place the first element in the container on the webpage and you make a function that adds +1 to the Array index so that the displayed element changes from array[0] to array[1] and you setInterval for the function so that it will repeat and will add +1 every time to change the array element (slide) displayed.